# i am trying to integrate card.io for phonegap android

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, card.io

I am trying to integrate card.io for phonegap android.i have added pluggins and also the java files but it gives me error "Uncaught ReferenceError: CardIOPGPlugin is not defined" on click "scanBtn".
This is the following code i have used in html page:

```
var onCardIOComplete = function(response) {
    console.log("card.io scan completed");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
};

var onCardIOCancel = function() {
    console.log("card.io scan cancelled");
};

$('#scanBtn').click(function() {
    CardIOPGPlugin.scan(onCardIOComplete, onCardIOCancel);
});
```

This is the following link which i used as reference : https://github.com/cubettech/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/card.io.

Comment: Just for a sanity check, do you have `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="CardIOPGPlugin.js"></script>` in your HTML as described in the docs? Also, are you using Angular by chance?

Comment: yes i have already added this in html page

Comment: I am not using angular